# MapBox GL JS marker offset

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using [MapBox GL JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Marker) to create a map with a custom marker:

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(container)
    .setLngLat([
        datacenters[country][city].coordinates.lng,
        datacenters[country][city].coordinates.lat
    ])
    .addTo(map);
```

However, I seem to have some kind of offset problem with the marker. The thing is: when zoomed out a bit, the bottom of the marker is not really pointing to the exact location:

[image: Marker when zoomed out a bit]

When I'm zooming in a bit further it reaches its destination and it's pointing to the exact spot.

[image: Marker when zoomed in]

I really love MapBox GL, but this particular problem is bugging me and I'd love to know how to solve it. When this is fixed my implementation is far more superior to the original mapping software I was using.

Comment: Out of interest, @egidius, are you planning on clustering these markers, and if you've done it, could you let me know how?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From Mapbox GL JS 0.22.0 you're able to set an offset option to the marker. https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Marker

For example to offset the marker so that it's anchor is the middle bottom (for your pin marker) you would use:

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(container, {
        offset: [-width / 2, -height]
    })
    .setLngLat([
        datacenters[country][city].coordinates.lng,
        datacenters[country][city].coordinates.lat
    ])
    .addTo(map);
```

Comment: Cool! I was using v0.21.0, so I guess my hack is still legit given my circumstances. Thank you so much. I'll just have to wait for v 0.22.0 to be released.

Comment: @Egidius It's now released https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Awesome!! Never have had to wait this short amount of time for a release

Comment: I take it the 'width' and 'height' are the width and height in px of the marker you're using? @AndrewHarvey Still struggling to get this to work! Even with the correct offset it remains inaccurate on zooming in and out...

Comment: Finally got it.... it turns out my width needed to be negative width / 2 and the height to be height * 2...

Comment: @HuwDavies The API description says "The offset in pixels as a PointLike object to apply relative to the element's top left corner. Negatives indicate left and up." Based on that I would have thought it would be [-width/2, -height]?

Comment: @AndrewHarvey strangely enough the height isn't negative. It's double. I guess people will have to experiment with their markers ;)

Comment: Mine works when I do negative width/2 and negative height

Comment: In the current version, the offset is relative to the _center_ of the marker, not the top left: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#pointlike

Answer (score 9):

New solution for mapbox-gl.js v1.0.0 - Marker objects now have an `anchor` option to set the position to align to the marker's Lat/Lng: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(container, {anchor: 'bottom');
```

This should cover most cases and is more reliable than a pixel offset in my experience.

Comment: This worked for me, using a similar marker to the questioner, without having to set an `offset`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an solution to my problem. It might be somewhat hacky, but it solves the positioning problem of the marker: I'm using a [Popup](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Popup) fill it with a font awesome map marker icon and remove it's "tooltip styled" borders:

Javascript:

```
map.on('load', function() {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    var icon = document.createElement('i');
    icon.dataset.city = city;

    icon.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var city = e.target.dataset.city;
        var country = e.target.dataset.country
        flyTo(datacenters[country][city].coordinates);
    });

    icon.classList.add('fa', 'fa-map-marker', 'fa-2x');
    container.appendChild(icon);

    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
            closeButton: false,
            closeOnClick: false
        })
        .setLngLat([
            datacenters[country][city].coordinates.lng,
            datacenters[country][city].coordinates.lat
        ])
        .setDOMContent(container)
        .addTo(map);
});
```

CSS:

```
.map div.mapboxgl-popup-content {
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.map .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
    display: none;
}
```

I just hope someone comes up with a real solution, because this feels kinda dirty to me. But hey: it does the job just fine!

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox Marker now has an element option see this link [Mapbox Marker](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#Marker). So instead of appending the icon HTML to the Div element you can simply add into the options when creating a marker.  I found this also gets rid of the offset problem. So using the code above you can do this....

```
var icon = document.createElement('i');
icon.classList.add('fas', 'fa-map-marker-alt');
icon.style.color = 'blue';
new mapboxgl.Marker(container, {anchor: 'center', offset: [0, 0], element: icon})
```

Also the CSS for the marker can be updated to allow a pointer

```
.mapboxgl-marker {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `offset: [0, 0]` hint, that resolved the problem for me.